# Regex with special chars like |

Tags: regex, expression, special-characters

I'm looking for a way to construct a long regex expression that includes several items with special chars that are regex commands as well, for example:

"Bath Tub | Black" and "Bath Tub | Green".

How do I use them as "string" with the | inside?

I thought about

```
(Bath Tub|Showers) \| (Black|Green)
```

but then again there are items like "Bath Tub | Green (light)" and "Bath Tub | Green (dark)" so I need to add that too, so I thought in some cases it would be the best solution to just take it like

```
"Bath Tub | Green (light)"|"Bath Tub | Green (dark)"
```

if that would work.

Any idea how to do it? I'm really horrible with regex and it is giving me a lot of headache, so I would appreciate any help!

Kind regards

Comment: What do you want to match exactly ?

Comment: What language / reggae flavor?

Comment: The parentheses are special too.

Comment: I want to match the name of div id's or class names. Language is JS

Answer (score 0):

You can add them all into alternation list:

```
Bath Tub|Showers|Black|Green(?: \((?:light|dark)\))?
```

Have a look at the [example](https://regex101.com/r/bQ1yW3/1).

The main point is that all of these alternatives can be added to the list (separated with `|`), and in case you have additional words after these strings, you can add them as *optional non-capturing groups* (`(?: \((?:light|dark)\))?`). Also, pay attention at the escaped round brackets - they will be matched as literals.

If you want to match a literal pipe symbol inside a string `|`, you should escape it: `\|`. See [this example](https://regex101.com/r/bQ1yW3/2).

To match all entries from `"Bath Tub | Green (light)"|"Bath Tub | Green (dark)"`, together with quotes, you can add optional groups with quotes at start and end of the pattern: `(?:")?(?:Bath Tub|Showers|Black|Green(?: \((?:light|dark)\))?)(?:")?`. See yet another [example](https://regex101.com/r/bQ1yW3/3).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try that and play around with it a bit and report back :)

Comment: Okay I found a fee problems regarding that.

I wanna use the regex expression as a filter, that allows me to grab only specific items out of a long list... sometimes I need Tubs that are Black but not Green and light but not dark.

How can I get it more like a list, where I predefine what should be found and what shouldnt?

Comment: The best approach is to create a single list of what you want to match, and then use it to obtain what you want. Say, to add the optional "filter" for all the items in the list, you can put the whole list into a capturing group and the other optional group will be applied to all the items: `(?:Bath Tub|Showers|Black|Green)(?: \((?:light|dark)\))?` Have a look: https://regex101.com/r/kI2dV3/1